# Transform XY plane entities to an arbitrary plane

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, 2d, plane

I have a profile entity in XY plane. I have to do an extrusion along a vector. So I have to bring the profile entity perpendicular to the extrusion vector. Extrusion vector can be a arbitrary one (Xi+Yj+Zk). Could you please provide some idea about vector base manipulation to bring the profile perpendicular to the extrusion vector?

Update

......

Profile in XY plane

Global up vector : (0,0,1)

Extrusion vector : (Xe,Ye,Ze)

Local right = Extrusion vector x Global up vector = (x1,y1,z1)
Local Left  = Extrusion vector x Local right      = (x2,y2,z2)

I assume I have to rotate the plane twice about Local right and Local Left.

So the angle is calculated for Local right = Atan(Xe.Y/Xe.Z) and the entity is rotated about Local right by calculated angle. and it is working fine

My question is how to calculate the angle for Local Left ?

If I summarize, I have to do the opposite of this one ([Mapping coordinates from plane given by normal vector to XY plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780646/mapping-coordinates-from-plane-given-by-normal-vector-to-xy-plane))

Comment: by Extrusion vector x Global up vector do you mean multiplication or cross product?

Comment: also, by `local left` you actually mean `local up`.  You only need right and up vectors for a plane.  Use those vectors in the negative direction for left and down vector equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your extrusion vector and one reference vector you can cross multiply them to retrieve your 2D planes' right vector in 3D space.

I usually use the `global up` vector as my reference.  So your `extrusion` vector cross multiplied with `global up` will result in a `local right` vector.  Another cross multiply between your `extrusion` vector and your new `local right` vector will result in a `local up` vector.

Once you get both your `local right` and `local up` vectors, those will be your planes `X` and `Y` vectors in 3D space.

Comment: Please check my, update, Your solution working partially only, may be my mistake too

Comment: If I summaries my question, How transform coordinates from one plane to another plane. what are the steps to do it?

Comment: This is opposite of my requirements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780646/mapping-coordinates-from-plane-given-by-normal-vector-to-xy-plane