# How to convert from 2D points to 3D points on a plane?

Tags: 3d, geometry, quaternions

I have some 3D points on a plane. The plane is defined by normal and constant. I need to work with the points in 2D and then convert them back to 3D. In order to convert the points to 2D I made a quaternion to rotate the plane to the xy-plane and I can transform the points with that (simply discarding the z-coord). After modifying the points in 2D I want to convert them back to 3D. I noticed that the same quaternion, if inverted, rotates the point back but I need to translate it too somehow, involving the plane's constant, but I don't know how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Projecting 3D points to 2D plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472048/projecting-3d-points-to-2d-plane)

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I need the inverse algorithm of that, projecting from 2D back to 3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your plane is given in Hessian normal form, i.e., a point `x` lies on the plane iff:

```
dot(n, x) - c = 0
```

with the unit normal `n`.

When you apply a rotation that aligns the plane parallel to the xy-plane to these points, they will have a z-component equal to `c`. Hence, to convert back from 2D to 3D, you simply need to add a z-component of `c` and apply the inverse rotation. Make sure that the above definition applies in your case. Sometimes, the form `dot(n, x) + c = 0` is used, which would produce a z-component of `-c`.

Note that this procedure is functionally suitable but computationally heavy. An alternative is to define a 3D basis on the plane and convert between 3D and 2D with this basis. You can find an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780646/mapping-coordinates-from-plane-given-by-normal-vector-to-xy-plane?rq=2).

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I did, I kept the z and put it back on the inverse rotation for all points and it worked.

Comment: do you have any code with the 3D basis solution, in any language? that would help a lot